How can i upgrade jenkins to the lates war file?
I am trying to upgarde jenkins to the lates war file.
I have downloaded the war file and installed java version 21.
i made a change to the jenkins.xml file and in the  section added where the java is located , ie so it would look like
      <executable>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe"</executable>

But when i restart the jenkins service it just gives an error that it cant start , no specific error.
I have also tried to upgrade from the Jenkins UI , same issue.
How can i upgrade to the latest ?

I'd you are running as a service, then it's probably stored the configuration in the SC database. Similar problem to those who install on Linux as a package then either edit the config manually or upgrade directly. Use the SC command to query and edit properly and restart. Or delete the service (not the actual install) SC delete Jenkins and recreate w/updated info.
